# Change div tag's attribute based on position()

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to parse a xml  in which I need to Change div tag's attribute based on position() for the first one alone. As you can see below, I've already used a apply template for the parent div. How can I apply the condition for just the first div alone inside apply template?

```
<div class="maintitle">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
</div>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <h3 class="sub title">
    <span>
      <a href="............"></a>
    </span>
  </h3>

  <div class="slide">

    <!-- ... html chunk ... -->

  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

but for the first div in apply template should come as

```
 <h3 class="sub title">
   <span>
     <a href="............"></a>
   </span>
 </h3>

 <div class="first slide">

   <!-- ... html chunk ... -->

 </div>
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. Could you please edit your post with complete XML, the XSLT you used, your expected output with proper explanation of what you want.

Comment: I'm looking for an option to avoid repeating the whole div with a condition.

Comment: A complete but minimal input XML, the complete XSLT you tried, and the expected complete output. Without these it is not quite easy to understand the problem. Could you please re-edit, I don't see an input XML at all..

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown what your input looks like, any answer will involve some guesswork.

But in general, there are two ways to make XSLT handle the first element of a series differently from others.

First, you can make two different templates, one for the first `title` element and one for the others:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
  <!--* handling for most title elements *-->
</
<xsl:template match="title[1]">
  <!--* handling for the first title *-->
</
```

In this case, that probably involves more duplication of the template code than one would like.

Second, you can use a conditional to surround the relevant code.  Here, using an XSL attribute constructor instead of a literal result attribute will simplify things:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
  <h3 class="sub title">
    <span>
      <a href="............"></a>
    </span>
  </h3>

  <div>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:text>first</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:text> slide</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <!-- ... html chunk ... -->

  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

These assume that:

- each `title` element in your input turns into one slide in your output;
- the `title` elements are siblings;
- the `title` elements are not intermixed with elements of other types.

If these assumptions don't hold, the way you write the `match` patterns or the `test` conditions will differ from what's shown.

Comment: yes your understanding is correct and the second option is similar to what i'm trying to. However your second option 
 ' <div>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:text>first</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:text> slide</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <!-- ... html chunk ... -->

  </div>
</xsl:template>'

gives an output like this

<div class="first slide"> 
but thats required only for position 1 and the remaining should be as 
<div class="slide">

Comment: yes your understanding is correct and the second option is similar to what i'm trying to. However your second option 
 `<div>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <xsl:text>first</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:text> slide</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <!-- ... html chunk ... -->

  </div>
</xsl:template>`

gives an output like this

`<div class="first slide"> 
but thats required only for position 1 and the remaining should be as 
<div class="slide">`

Comment: If the code shown is emitting the value "first slide" for all titles, then the titles are not all siblings, and the assumptions listed are *not* correct.  If you cannot figure out how to adjust the test, you will need to learn to provide better information about the input.